# JSON structure - authorize user menu

Tags: json, database, authentication, authorization

I want to showing menu by user login. etc: if I login with user1, just show menu1, menu2, menu3. if I login with user2, just show menu2 and menu3.

I already create JSON structure per module.

```
tiles :
        {
                module1 : [
                    {
                        "header":"Data Peserta",
                        "subheader":"Kepesertaan",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://log",
                        "route":"datapeserta"
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header1",
                        "subheader":"Kepesertaan",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://delete",
                        "route":"first"
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header1",
                        "subheader":"Kepesertaan",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://line-charts",
                        "route":"first"
                    }                       
                ],

                module2 : [
                    {
                        "header":"Header2",
                        "subheader":"Layanan dan Manfaat",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://add-filter",
                        "route":"first"
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header2",
                        "subheader":"Layanan dan Manfaat",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://add-filter",
                        "route":"first"
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header2",
                        "subheader":"Layanan dan Manfaat",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://action",
                        "route":"first"
                    }                       
                ],                      

                module3 : [
                    {
                        "header":"Header3",
                        "subheader":"Investasi",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://activate",
                        "route":"first"
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header3",
                        "subheader":"Investasi",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://display-more",
                        "route":"first"
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header3",
                        "subheader":"Investasi",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://customize",
                        "route":"first"
                    }                       
                ]
        }
```

So, each module have a menu, and all have 3 module. how to edit this json structure for user authorize? where I put object for user to this JSON model?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that clear to me but if you want to incorporate it in same JSON then you can put "userlist" as an array property. Some thing like this (I am taking example from module1):

`{
                        "header":"Data Peserta",
                        "subheader":"Kepesertaan",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://log",
                        "route":"datapeserta",
                        "userlist":["user1","user2","user3"]
                    },
                    {
                        "header":"Header1",
                        "subheader":"Kepesertaan",
                        "icon":"sap-icon://delete",
                        "route":"first",
                        "userlist":["user2","user3"]
                    }`

This will provide you controlling access with more granularity. In this case within the Module which user to show which Header/Subheader etc.